# Can't construct object from parameter in constructor called by PyYAML

Tags: python, python-3.x, yaml, pyyaml

I have a YAML file that looks like this:

```
---
!Frog
    name: tree frog
    colour: green
    friends:
        - !Frog
          name: motorbike frog
        - !Frog
          name: blue arrow frog
```

And a python program that uses PyYAML to create objects according to the file:

```
import yaml

class Frog():
    def __init__(self, name, colour="", friends=None):
        self.name = name
        self.colour = colour
        self.friends = {}
        if friends != None:
            for f in friends:
                self.friends[f.name] = f
        print("{}'s friends: {}".format(self.name, self.friends))

# Constructor for YAML
def frogConstructor(loader, node) :
    fields = loader.construct_mapping(node)
    return Frog(**fields)

yaml.add_constructor('!Frog', frogConstructor)

f = open("frog.yaml")
loaded = yaml.load(f)
```

As you can see in the above code, I'm trying to make a `self.friends` dictionary from the `friends` parameter (where the key is the frog's name and the value is the actual frog object) to the `__init__` method. However, the code above results in the following output:

```
tree frog's friends: {}
motorbike frog's friends: {}
blue arrow frog's friends: {}
```

As you can see, the `self.friends` dictionary is empty for all three of the frogs, but the tree frog should have two friends. If I simply make `self.friends = friends`, it works as expected: `self.friends` is a list of the friend frogs. What am I doing wrong?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

That things work if you do `self.friends = friends` is not so strange. You assign an initially empty list to `self.friends`, a list that later gets appended to by the YAML parser.

If you want that list to be filled before constructing your `Frog()`, you'll have to provide the `deep=True` parameter for `construct_mapping()`, doing so will make sure the underlying non-scalar constructs are created first as well as the scalar ones.

```
def frogConstructor(loader, node):
    fields = loader.construct_mapping(node, deep=True)
    return Frog(**fields)
```

There are however a few more problems with your code (none of them prohibiting the above to function though):

- there is only one `None`, so it is more appropriate to use `if friends is not None:` than `if friends != None:`
- `yaml.load` is unsafe, so if you have no complete control over your input, that might mean a wiped disc (or worse). PyYAML doesn't warn you for that (in my [`ruamel.yaml`](https://pypi.python.org/pypi/ruamel.yaml/) parser you explicitly have to provide the unsafe `Loader` to prevent a warning message).
- If `tree frog` is narcissist enough to consider itself a friend of itself, or if one of its friends considers `tree frog` a friend, you might want to use an anchor and alias to indicate so (and not just use the same name on a different `Frog`), and that is not going to work with the simple constructor you are using.
- `frogConstructor`, as a function name, should not be camel case, use `frog_constructor` instead.

Because of the above, I would not use the `deep=True` parameter but go for a safer, and more complete solution by having a two stage constructor:

```
from ruamel import yaml

class Frog():
    def __init__(self, name):
        self.name = name

    def set_values(self, colour="", friends=None):
        self.colour = colour
        self.friends = {}
        if friends is not None:
            for f in friends:
                self.friends[f.name] = f
        print("{}'s friends: {}".format(self.name, self.friends))

    def __repr__(self):
        return "Frog({})".format(self.name)

# Constructor for YAML
def frog_constructor(loader, node):
    fields = loader.construct_mapping(node)
    frog = Frog(fields.pop('name'))
    yield frog
    frog.set_values(**fields)

yaml.add_constructor('!Frog', frog_constructor, yaml.SafeLoader)

f = open("frog.yaml")
loaded = yaml.safe_load(f)
```

with that you can parse this `frog.yaml`:

```
!Frog &tree_frog
    name: tree frog
    colour: green
    friends:
        - !Frog
          name: motorbike frog
          friends:
            - *tree_frog
        - !Frog
          name: blue arrow frog
```

to get as output:

```
tree frog's friends: {'blue arrow frog': Frog(blue arrow frog), 'motorbike frog': Frog(motorbike frog)}
motorbike frog's friends: {'tree frog': Frog(tree frog)}
blue arrow frog's friends: {}
```